# $\int_C z^2 \sin(1/z)dz$ where c is the positively oriented unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

how to find the value of $\int_C z^2 \sin(1/z)dz$ on unit circle $C$, I tried by using Cauchy integral formula but do not find correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change of variables $z=\dfrac{1}{Z}$ which leaves unit circle $C$ invariant (but changes its orientation, do you see why ?) as you would do for a real integral. Your integral becomes :

$$I=\int_{z \in C_+} \dfrac{1}{Z^2} \sin(Z) \frac{-dZ}{Z^2}=-\int_{Z \in C_-} \dfrac{1}{Z^4} \sin(Z) dZ=$$

$$-\int_{Z \in C_-} \dfrac{1}{Z^4} (Z-\dfrac{Z^3}{3!}+\dfrac{Z^5}{5!}-...) dZ=$$

$$+\int_{Z \in C_+} (\dfrac{1}{Z^3} -\dfrac{1}{3!}\dfrac{1}{Z}+\dfrac{1}{5!}Z+...) dZ$$

(note the change of orientation has been compensated by the minus sign)

As the residue is the coefficient $r=-\dfrac{1}{3!}$ of $\dfrac{1}{Z}$, the integral is

> > $$I=2i\pi r = -\dfrac{i\pi}{3}$$

Comment: z=1/z then dz=-(1/z2 dz)

Comment: You are right for keeping the minus sign (I had done the error of taking the absolute value of the jacobian as I would have done on a real integral).

Answer (score 1):

Use Residue Theorem. The residue at $0$ is $-\frac 1 {3!}$ as seen from the series expansion of $\sin (\frac 1 z)$ so the answer is $-2 \pi i \cdot \frac 1 {3!}$. [The residue at $0$ is the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$ in the Laurent series expansion and it is easy to what this is from the series expansion].